# Where does Yajur Veda have Mantra Pushpam hymn?

Tags: scripture, yajur-veda

Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra_pushpam) confirms that Mantra Pushpam is taken from Yajur Veda. Where this hymn can be found? Whether in Krishna Yajur Veda or Shukla Yajur Veda or both? And also quote the number of hymn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in Triyugi Narayan Mani's answer, the Mantra Pushpam is a collection of 10 mantras from the Taitariya Aranyaka (TA) associted with the Yajurveda. Exact location is **TA KAnda 1, Prasna 22| 1-10.**

I am giving the translations of these 10 mantras.

> 1) Yo apam pushpam veda.... ya evam veda.
>
> ...
>
> He who reagrds the water as Pushpa, becomes endowed with Pushpa
>   (abode), successors and knowledge (pashu). He who knows that Moon
>   nourishes the waters, becomes endowed with Pushpa (abode), successors
>   and knowledge (pashu), know thus.
>
> 2) yo apAm Ayatanam veda, AyatanavAn bhavati... ya evam veda.
>
> ....
>
> He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode (
>   AyatanavAn bhavati, this phrase is repeated in all mantras). He who
>   knows the waters as the abode of Agni, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   He who knows the abode of Agni, becomes possessed of an abode. He who
>   knows the water as the abode of Agni, becomes possessed of an abode,
>   Know thus.
>
> 3) He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   Know Vayu as the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   (Know) abode of Vayu, becomes possessed of an abode. Know waters as
>   the abode of VAyu, becomes possessed of an abode. Know thus.
>
> 4) He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   (He who knows) that burning Sun as the abode of waters, becomes
>   possessed of an abode... Know thus.
>
> 5) He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   Moon is the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode. Know the
>   abode of Moon's rays; becomes possessed of an abode. (Know) waters as
>   the abode of Moon's rays; becomes possessed of an abode. Know thus.
>
> 6)He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode. The
>   asterisms are the abode of waters;  becomes possessed of an abode.
>   Know the abode of asterisms; becomes possessed of an abode.(Know)
>   Waters as the abode of asterisms; becomes possessed of an abode; Know
>   thus.
>
> 7)  He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   Rain in the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode. He who
>   knows the abode of Parjanya, becomes possessed of an abode. (Know)
>   Waters as the abode of Parjanya, becomes possessed of an abode. Know
>   thus.
>
> 8) He who knows the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   Time (Seasons) is the abode of waters, becomes possessed of an abode.
>   He who knows the abode of time, becomes possessed of an abode. (Know)
>   Waters as the abode of time, becomes possessed of an abode. Know thus.
>
> 9) Yo apsu nAvam pratishthithAm veda, pratyeva tishthati, ime vai lokA
>   apsu pratishthitAh, tadeshA abhyanuktA ||
>
> ....
>
> He who established firmly in the waters, is able to be established in
>   his own world. The worlds that are seen are established in the waters.
>   This has been declared.
>
> 10) apAm rasam udayam san.... tam vo grhnAmi uttamam ||
>
> ....
>
> The essence (rasa) of all rises in the waters. This essence is
>   collected from the pure Sun-World. The water are the essence of the
>   essences. We receive the Supreme essence (rasa).

Comment: Nice to see English translation. Do you have hard-copy of TA?

Comment: I have a book (hard copy) on Veda mantras that has all these mantras. But, no i don't have a hard copy of the whole TA.@TriyugiNarayanMani

Comment: Looks like they have deeper meaning. What do "waters" and "abode" here mean?

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes they must have deeper meanings, but i know as much as is written :D.. the translations are according to rishi aurobindo, sayana, bhaskara bhatta.. actually water is described here as everything.. as is done in other Veda mantras like **apo va idam sarvam**..

Answer (score 5):

`Pushpam Mantra` is present in [22nd Anuvaka of the 1st Prapathika of Taittiriya Aranyaka of Yajurveda](http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/).

[image]

Below is its transliteration in English.

[image]

For English translation, please check Rickross's answer.

Comment: So it is not actually Yajur Veda

Comment: @Ajay Aranyaka are related to Vedas. And the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra_pushpam) link you have mentioned in question says that `This mantra is taken from Taittiriya Aranyakam of Yajur Veda.`